# Auto Layout Constraint from UICollectionViewCell to View from ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView which can scroll horizontally. 
It its cell I would like to add constraint to main view get from ViewController.

Because this is cell of UICollectionView and not his subview, xcode report error that hierarchy is wrong. How to do something like that?

EDIT :

The purpose or effect that I want it is something like that :

I have UICollectionView scrolling horizontal. Cells of this collection view are screen pages. on that screens are labels.
When user scroll through pages in collection view I would like that label will scroll to the left/right edge of the screen that stay there and disappear with another page. Something like group table view section header but horizontally.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to add a constraint on a cell to the parent view of the collection view? What purpose would that serve?

Comment: ok, I will edit my question for that.

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement the scroll view's delegate scrollViewDidScroll method and adjust the position of the label based on the offset of the scroll view.

Comment: My solution will be to add constraint from Label to Main View - left equal with priority 900 and constraint from label to page view - Right  more or equal with priority 1000. But I don't know how to set constraint from label to main view

Comment: You can't have a constraint to an item outside the parent view. Since the label that you're referring to is inside your cell you can't have a constraint to parent of the collection view.

Comment: Is there no way to go around this?

Comment: I would suggest creating a visual mockup of what you're trying to accomplish (layout example of exactly where the label should be and what it should do while scrolling). It'll make it easier to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers, but nothing works for me. 
What I did is to create 2 constraints:

```
cell.left equal label.left : priority 499
cell.right greateOrEqual label.right
```

I save left constraint an on the scroll move I did:

```
- (void) scrollOffsetChange: (CGPoint) offset
{
    int x = abs(((int)offset.x%(int)self.frame.size.width));
    self.topLableLeftConstraint.constant = x;
    self.topLabels.alpha = 1 - (x/self.frame.size.width)*(x/self.frame.size.width);
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

and I even ended disappear effect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to have these labels as part of your cells, it sounds like you might be better off implementing them as **supplementary views** - they're what `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` uses for its section headers and footers.

You'd need to implement some methods to provide the views themselves, as well as layout attributes for them. Here's a link to some relevant reference material in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW7